# How can i get rails app to only apply twitter bootstrap css to only selected pages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I have an app, that will have a frontend where everyone can see and a backend for admin to manage the data. I want that all pages related to the backend to have twitter bootstrap applied while the other pages to use a different css. I'm already loading different layouts depending on the controller. How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple: put the Twitter Bootstrap CSS file only in the layouts you're using for the backend!